# MagicSquare using java functions

Tags: java

For some reason this thing goes out of bounds if `n` is not declared above for example if `n=3;` then there's no problems but if I rely on user input for the value of `n` it goes out of bounds.

```
import java.io.*;
public class MagicSquare_Cubz {
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(System.in));

int n;
int [][] array; // = new int [z][z];
int i=0; 
int j = n/2;
int k = 1;

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException{
        new MagicSquare_Cubz();
    }


    public MagicSquare_Cubz() throws IOException {
        System.out.print("MAGIC SQUARE\n");
        System.out.print("============\n");
        System.out.print("Enter a number: ");

        n=Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
        //n=o;
        array = new int [n][n];
        //problem.. for some reason the array goes out of bounds if n is not declared... 
        disp();

            if(n%2!=0){
                exe();
                disp();
            }

            else{
                System.out.print("Enter odd numbers only");
            }

    }

    public void exe() throws IOException{

    System.out.println("IT WORKS " + n);

        while(k<=n*n){

            array[i][j] = k++;
            i--; // Making one step upward
            j++; // Moving one step to the right
                if(i<0 && j>n-1){ // Condition for the top-right corner element
                   i = i+2;
                   j--;  
                }       
                if(i<0) // Wrapping around the row if it goes out of boundary
                   i = n-1;

                if(j>n-1) // Wrapping around the column if it goes out of boundary
                   j = 0;

                if(array[i][j]>0){ // Condition when the cell is already filled
                   i = i+2;
                   j--; 
                }     
        }             

    }

    public void disp() throws IOException{

        for(int x=0 ; x<n ; x++){
            for(int y=0 ; y<n ; y++){
                System.out.print(array[x][y]+ " ");
            }
            System.out.println("");

        }
    }


}
```

Comment: please add your stack trace

Comment: Looks like int j = n/2; without n having a value could be something to look into.  Not sure why you're expecting not to declare n.  If you want to use n, I would expect declaring it is required...

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
j = n / 2;
```

after

```
n=Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
```

Answer (score 0):

just declare j in the main class i.e int j;
then initialise it in if block.

```
if(n%2!=0){
                      j = n/2; 
                    exe();
                    disp();
                }
```